# Mapping a network drive in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-prompt, windows-7-x64, network-drive

I want to access shared folders in the network using the local drive letter. 
(Eg. \\shared_drive\folder as Z:)

I am able to use the "Map Drive" option from "My Computer" window to do this.

But is there any command to map a network drive in windows 7 or later versions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following command is working for me.

net use Z: \\shared_drive\folder